# Can't catch TYPE_NOT_FOUND exception

Tags: exception, try-catch, abap

I am calling the `cl_abap_typedescr=>describe_by_name` method. It could possibly throw a `TYPE_NOT_FOUND` exception. I am coming form c# and in c# it would be quite easy to catch such an error. But in ABAP i am not able to catch the exception.

It starts with the fact that I can't use the `TYPE_NOT_FOUND` exception object in my code. It just does not exist. It continues with the fact that catching `CX_ROOT` won't help either. It just ignores my try catch clause and crashes:

```
TRY .
  descr_ref0 ?= cl_abap_typedescr=>describe_by_name('iabc1').
CATCH cx_root.
  BREAK-POINT.
ENDTRY.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume you need the type-casting, so have provided an additional step for it.

This syntax isn't as elegant as the new syntax, but it's the only way I could get your example to compile:

```
  data descr_ref1 type ref to cl_abap_typedescr.

  call method cl_abap_typedescr=>describe_by_name(
    exporting  p_name         = 'abc1'
    receiving  p_descr_ref    = descr_ref1
    exceptions type_not_found = 1 ).

  if sy-subrc <> 0.
    break-point.
  else.
    descr_ref0 ?= descr_ref1.
  endif.
```

edit:

You can tell which type of exceptions is used by looking at the method:

[image]

or alternatively you can use the "Pattern" command in the editor to get the correct syntax.

Comment: Well, I am pretty new to abap. I was hoping that i could get around this but well... thanks :)

Comment: @thefiloe obviously when you write your own methods, you would always use class-based exceptions; but because of backward compatibility, the old stuff will stick around in SAP standard.

Answer (score 5):

`TYPE_NOT_FOUND` is [not a class-based exception](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_70/en/ABENEXCEPTIONS_NON_CLASS.htm). You'll need to use the [old syntax](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_70/en/ABAPCALL_METHOD_PARAMETERS.htm#&ABAP_ADDITION_5@5@) and assign a non-zero value to each exception, then check `SY-SUBRC` whether that value reappears.

Comment: The links are broken.